# Wordpress get the latest plugin installed details

Tags: plugins

I dont know which plugin is giving the error "bp_setup_current_user was called incorrectly"

calling before the buddypress installed.
How can I get the details of latest plugin installed in the wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you to use `DEBUG` in `wp-config.php` :

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); 
ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

This will log errors and put all of them in a log file you will find in `wp-content/debug.log`

Comment: I tired deactivating all the plugins still the admin panel doe's not show anything.. I don't what is the problem